# Display the icon to datatable that value is integer from database

Tags: angular, html-table

Good day! I'm having a hard time to display an icon in my view which value is an integer. I want to retrieve the data from database as icon

[image: This the list of my rating icon in moday]

So in my modal is a list of rating icon and if I choose the first icon it will save in my database as an integer or as a value of "1" and if I choose the second icon it will save as "2" and so on.

[image: This is my datatable]

So what I want to do is to display the selected icon in my data table

*This is my code in my data table, where the icon need to display*

```
<table datatable [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Rating Icon</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let x of question">
            <td>{{x.text}}</td>
            <td>
                <!-- {{x.rating_icon}}                                   -->
            </td>
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size: 20px; cursor:pointer;color:#2386bf; " (click)="editModal(x.id)"></i>&nbsp;
                <i class="fa fa-remove" style="font-size: 20px; cursor:pointer;color:#e43a3a; " (click)="archiveQuestion(x.id)"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope someone can help me with this. thanks in advance

Comment: Am I right your trying to display different Rating Icons depending on your "Enums" Value?

Comment: @marvstar yes your right and thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to display different elements (in your case Icons) is to use `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitchCase`.

lets call your Enum EIconType.

In your Component you define your Enum as follow:

```
 eIconType= EIconType;
```

By defining it like this you can use it in your HTML

In your HTML you use `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitchCase` depending on a default icon. So lets say you got a default icon and none was selected you should use `*ngSwitchCase` otherwise you should use `*ngIf`.

HTML :

```
<!-- ngIf -->
<div *ngIf="eIconType.Star">
   <img src="yourPath/StartIcon">
</div>
<div *ngIf="eIconType.Thumb">
   <img src="yourPath/ThumbIcon">
</div>
...


<!-- ngSwitchCase -->
<div [ngSwitch]="yourObjectAttributeEnumValue">
<div *ngSwitchCase="eIconType.Star">
   <img src="yourPath/StartIcon">
</div>
<div *ngSwitchCase="eIconType.Thumb">
   <img src="yourPath/ThumbIcon">
</div>
...
<div *ngSwitchDefault>
   <img src="yourPath/DefaultRatingIcon">
</div>
```

I hope this can help you.

Ps: Ask me if something is unclear.